# 3dCharacter in Unity Continues jumping in the air

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to follow Imphenzia's youtube tutorial on Unity3d and i've basically followed his code to a tee (1:28:00 in the following video) and my character continues to jump in the air. Not sure what im missing here and its driving me crazy.

The video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwZpJzpE2lQ&t=5342s&ab_channel=Imphenzia

the code:

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

```
private bool jumpKeyWasPressed;
private float horizontalInput;
private Rigidbody rigidBodyComponent;
private bool isGrounded;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rigidBodyComponent = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        
        jumpKeyWasPressed = true;
    }
    horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    

    

}
//Fixed update is called once every physics update
private void FixedUpdate()
{


  
        if (isGrounded != true) //if (isGrounded == false) works too
        {
            return;
        }

        if (jumpKeyWasPressed)
        {
            rigidBodyComponent.AddForce(Vector3.up * 5, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            jumpKeyWasPressed = false;
        }

        rigidBodyComponent.velocity = new Vector3(horizontalInput, rigidBodyComponent.velocity.y, 0);

 
}
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)

{
    // use ' collision. ' toget^^info using ^^^^^
    isGrounded = true;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was simply missing the line of code - `private void OnCollisionExit`. but he answers that later on, and removes the code that was written. my bad!